# Is is possible to get audio notifications working for subfolders for Apple Mail on macos?

Tags: macos, email

I want to receive audio notifications for email that lands in a particular subfolder of the Inbox. The filtering is done server side so I can't use a rule to generate a audio notification.

I tried accomplishing this with a smart folder/mailbox  but I'm not getting an audio notification for new email arriving in the subfolder.

Is it possible to get an audio notification on individual subfolders?

I can get audio notifications when the email lands directly in the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, the "New messages sound" setting in Mail -> Preferences -> General is not related to the "New message notifications" setting.

So it does not appear to be possible to turn on audio notifications on/off for subfolders. The audio notification only can happen when an email lands in the inbox.